# WordPress updates overwrite .svn folder

Tags: wordpress, svn

We're using Subversion to keep track of the changes our web team makes to our Wordpress site. We do nothing more than modify and update our custom theme, but we have difficulty updating the Wordpress core and plugins.

Right now, I have my checked out copy working on a local WordPress install. However, when I run the automatic WordPress updates on this local copy, the updates overwrite the .svn folders in the respective subfolders, resulting in a "Directory .svn containing working copy admin area is missing" error when I try to commit the update.

How can I do these updates automatically without overwriting the .svn folder? As of now I am resorting to copying the files in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just maintaining your theme, you should not have the whole wordpess install under svn but just the theme. I also think in your case it doesn't make sense to actually use a working copy of your repository in the actual live site. In your case I'd keep a working copy of your theme somewhere on your server and then rsync on demand to your theme folder. This way you can update wordpress and your plugins automatically and without problems.